# Sed expression to convert only certain lines starting with some example phrase

Tags: sed, backreference

There's an example file with a regular text. In some places of the document there's a mix of the following lines:

```
| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) |
```

There's the following sed expression to convert the lines to the required form:

```
sed 's#\([^[]*.\)\([^\.]*.\([^\.]*\)[^)]*.\)#\1\3\2#g'
```

How to apply this sed expression to only those lines that start with `| ![](` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not quite right: `.` when unescaped matches any char. Also, note you do not need to escape `.` chars inside bracket expressions.

I suggest the following command:

```sh
sed '/^|[[:space:]]!\[](/s#\(|[[:space:]]!\[\)\(]([^().]*\.\([^|.]*\)\.[^()]*)\)#\1\3\2#g'
```

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/tJqxrt).

Here, the POSIX BRE pattern matches

- `/^|[[:space:]]!\[](/` - any line starting with `|`, whitespace, and then `![](` text
- `s#\(|[[:space:]]!\[\)\(]([^().]*\.\([^|.]*\)\.[^()]*)\)#\1\3\2#g` -

  - `\(|[[:space:]]!\[\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `|`, a whitespace, `![` text
  - `\(]([^().]*\.` - Group 2 start: `](`, then any zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `.`, then a `.` (note it is escaped)

    - `\([^|.]*\)` - Group 3 (`\3`): any zero or more chars other than `|` and `.`
  - `\.[^()]*)\)` - (still Group 2): `.` char, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.

The replacement is the concatenation of Group 1, 3 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your `s` command with `/| !\[](/`.

`[` is interpreted as regex and to avoid this it must be escaped.